# Is there an easy way to strongly suggest page breaks at new sections?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, page-breaking

I have a large document with plenty of sections (*scrbook*, `\addsec`). Is there an easy way to influence the behaviour of `\addsec` so that a page break will be quite welcome in those places? As for now, page breaks occur in unwelcome places too (as for this very document), like after one-two lines of a new section. I thought of using something like `\pagebreak[n]` and adjusting that `n` in order to control those awaited page breaks. However adding that manually at every new section and changing manually every single `n` is no solution for me since there are about 100 sections. Could this be done once for the whole document? Somewhere in the preamble maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [nowidow](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nowidow/nowidow.pdf) package provides this functionality. You can specify the minimum number of lines that you would like a section to show at a pagebreak.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\addsec{Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-4]\\
a few\\
more\\
lines\\
\addsec{Broken section}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Result without `\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}`:

[image]

Result with `\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}`:

[image]

Note that the page height is still kept constant, this means that the vertical space between paragraphs on the first page is enlarged quite a bit. If you want the regular space between paragraphs with some unused space at the bottom, then you can use `\raggedbottom`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[defaultlines=3,all]{nowidow}
\raggedbottom
[...]
```